# NextJS/React ignore parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS and i  have A Layout component as a wrapper in _app.js:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  );
}
```

The Layout component simply has a Top navigation in it for navigating the website.

So my problem is in some pages/routes in my app i Don't want the navigation bar to be visible/rendered because it will be useless just taking up space or it doesn't make sense to have a navigation bar at top.

For example in the admin dashboard /admin or /about

So how i can simply ignore that parent Layout component?

I have this solution with NextJS but im not really sure if it's the correct way/most efficient way of doing that:

```
// Layout.js
const router = useRouter();

 if (router.route === "/dashboard" || router.route === "/about") {
    return <Fragment></Fragment>;
  } else {
    // return layout
  }
```

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `<Layout>` component to your pages. So you can make multiple reusable Layout Components for your use-cases.

For example, if you have a webshop you might want to have a completely different layout for you checkout, and for your profile pages. Just move it to all your page objects and you're fine.

```js
const MyPage = () => {
   return (
      <CheckoutLayout>
         ...
      </CheckoutLayout>
   );
}
export default MyPage
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach for me because im going to have multiple layout.Thank you

Comment: For those who just want ignore the parent component in certain pages check @Bhojendra Rauniyar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're implementing it correctly. However, what if you have further routes? You can simply perform like this:

```
const noLayout = ['/dashboard', '/about']
if(noLayout.indexOf(router.route) > -1) {
  return <Fragment></Fragment>
} else {
   // ...
}
```